# discord.py bot repeating messages

Tags: discord, discord.py

hi i am trying to make a discord.py bot so i can have a gif chat channel but when someone types a message in that channel then my bot starts repeating his message, pls help if u know.

my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open("gif_chater.json", "r+") as file:
        data=json.load(file)
        if str(message.channel.id) in data:
            if message.content.startswith("https://tenor.com/"):
                print("wOw")
            if not message.content.startswith("https://tenor.com/") and not message.author.id == "760083241133932544":
                await message.channel.send("lol pls use gifs in this channel : )")
                await message.delete()
                exit
```

Comment: What do you mean repeating? It works when a user sends message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The [on_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message) event

The issue is that the bot is constantly responding to itself, and it's because the `on_message` event triggers not just when users send a message but also when the bot sends a message. As such, once it tells the user that they must only post tenor gifs, it reacts to its own message and goes into an infinite loop, posting and deleting its responses.

#### Preventing the bot from responding to itself

To prevent the bot from responding to it's own messages, you should add a check at the start of the event [like in the discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
...
```

#### Also, the ID check at the end

The last condition in your code before it decides to send a message is checking the ID of the messenger (`not message.author.id == "760083241133932544"`). I don't know whether it's meant to avoid deleting you or the bot's messages but regardless, the check itself is bugged. [`message.author.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.id) returns an **integer** but is then being compared to a **string**, and due to the conflicting types, will always return False.

To fix it, change your ID to an integer by removing the quotes: `not message.author.id == 760083241133932544`. As well, you should use the not-equals operator `!=` instead of `not` to improve readability: `message.author.id != 760083241133932544`.

Also, since you already checked if the message starts with the website link, you can use an `elif` statement instead of rechecking the condition, since `else/elif` guarantees that the previous condition was false (aka, that the message didn't start with the website link):

```
if message.content.startswith("https://tenor.com/"):
    print("wOw")
elif message.author.id != 760083241133932544:
    await message.channel.send("lol pls use gifs in this channel : )")
    await message.delete()
```

#### Fixes combined

With the new changes, your function could look something like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Don't respond to the bot's own messages
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    with open("gif_chater.json") as file:
        data = json.load(file)

    if str(message.channel.id) in data:
        if message.content.startswith("https://tenor.com/"):
            print("wOw")
        elif message.author.id != 760083241133932544:
            await message.channel.send("lol pls use gifs in this channel : )")
            await message.delete()
```